# How to point domain to another hosting server?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, dns, hosting

I am a desktop programmer and have just been in websites for few months. I create websites using wordpress and I manage all necessary setups in cPanel. Some of my old sites are currently hosted in Godaddy and everything went smoothly until it run very slow and I decided to move everything to the nearest server provider in my country.

I've searched a lot and what I've done is moved all the web files and databases. I decided to leave the domain at Godaddy as domain transfer costs money. So the last step is to point the domain to the new server IP address but when I changed the DNS nameserver to the new server IP address, entering the site directs me to the hosting site like https://godaddy.com and not my own site. I understand that I didn't do anything that tells the domain where the website files directory is but I could not find anything related to that in google too. All the last step is to change the DNS nameserver.

A detailed explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your domain name + IP where your website files and db hosted? I can check DNS record for you and guide you accordingly. As it's super simple and easy

Comment: Update the domain DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The true solution is to add domain-addon with it's clear directory path / root folder so that the domain could find the web files.

Answer (score 0):

After login to GoDaddy : Go to https://dcc.godaddy.com/manage/yourdomainname.com/dns

Change name server to default name server

Add new A record as below

Name = @, Value = IP, TTL= 1 Hour

Add CNAME if you would like to use www as default domain

Name = www, Value = @, TTL = 1 Hour

You just need is A record point towards new server IP, CNAME if you want to use www version or any sub domain, MX Record if using anything for mail, NS to default, SOA no change.